# ajax waiting is too long

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have no problem in localhost but when i uploaded into a server waiting become too slow.

[image of speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQGGK.png)

here is my Ajax code:

```
$('button[value="submit"]').click(function() {
        var dataSelect = $( "#select-store" ).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {part: 'available-food', value: dataSelect},
            url: 'http://localhost/xxx/xxx/sss.php',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#delivery').fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $('#store').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-12');
                });
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#show-foods').html(response);
                $('.food-hover').css('opacity', '0');
                $('.food').hover(function() {
                    $(this).find('.food-hover').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 200);
                }, function(){
                    $(this).find('.food-hover').animate({'opacity': '0'}, 100);
                });

                addToCart();
            }
        });
});
```

and add to cart:

```
function addToCart() {
        $('#add-to-cart').click(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();

            $('.shop').animate({left: 0}, 300, 'swing');
            $('.body-overlay').css('display', 'block');
            open = true;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {part: 'add-to-cart', food_id: value, quantity: 1},
                url: 'http://localhost/xxx/xxx/zzz.php',
                beforeSend: function() {},
                complete: function() {},
                success: function(response) {
                    $('.shop #cart-list-items').html(response);
                    updateTotalCart();
                    updateTotalPrice();
                }
            });
        });
}
```

and updateTotalCart:

```
    function updateTotalCart () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {part: 'update-total-cart'},
            url: 'http://localhost/xxx/xxx/www.php',
            beforeSend: function() {},
            complete: function() {},
            success: function(response){
                $('.open-basket span').html(response);
            }
    });
}
```

and updateTotalPrice:

```
function updateTotalPrice () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {part: 'update-total-price'},
            url: 'http://localhost/xxx/xxx/aaa.php',
            beforeSend: function() {},
            complete: function() {},
            success: function(response){
                $('.basket footer #total-price').html(response);
            }
    });
}
```

what i have to do?

i have too many ajax.

Comment: Have you tested your service side codes to see how fast they are? I

Comment: well I doubt it is the JavaScript code

Comment: Have you tried `aync:true` in ajax calls ?

Comment: @Dhwani - that would be the default setting, and the only viable option in modern browsers.

Comment: Did you observe the call status via Chrome dev tools?

Comment: https://scaleyourcode.com/blog/article/27

Comment: @epascarello i remove the tag. :)

Comment: Looks like the request goes through right away, but you're waiting almost four seconds to get a response from the server, so most likely something on the server is the issue, not the posted code.

Comment: @ali no but i will do it. Mamnoon :)

Comment: @zennin yes i did.